# C++ VS2010 Unresolved symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

I really hate this problem that the compiler tells me

```
"err LNK2019: Reference to unresolved external symbol".
```

Unlike other compiler errors, I can not jump to this problem by double-clicking it.

It always takes me a tremendous amount of time to figure out what I did wrong.

For example, from the error message

```
Error   9   error LNK2019: Reference to unresolved symbol ""public: class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > & __thiscall clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap::Content(void)" (?Content@clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap@@QAEAAV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@XZ)" in Funktion ""private: void __thiscall CCompiler::pSerializeJoinBigUnsignedCharMap(class clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap &,struct _iobuf *)" (?pSerializeJoinBigUnsignedCharMap@CCompiler@@AAEXAAVclsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap@@PAU_iobuf@@@Z)".    m:\compiler.obj voice
```

I can not see at all where I should look for the error.

Am I missing something here? I don't see where the error is located, and the fact that I can not jump to the problem by double-clicking it indicates to me that VS2010 does not know either.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: LET ME GUESS: you missing the function `std::string clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap::Content(void)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CCompiler::pSerializeJoinBigUnsignedCharMap` (from `compiler.obj`) is using a method (`clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap::Content()`) that's defined in a header, but not implemented within any of the linked source files.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the message it says:

```
in Funktion ""private: void __thiscall CCompiler::pSerializeJoinBigUnsignedCharMap(class clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap &,struct _iobuf *)"
```

so in the function `CCompiler::pSerializeJoinBigUnsignedCharMap`,
there is a **unreferenced symbol**

```
clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap::Content(void)
```

the linker cannot link with `clsJoinBigUnsignedCharMap::Content`, it has no compiled code for it.